# OCaml higher order functions

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, iteration, ocaml, dynamic-programming

Somebody please explain the algorithm in this problem for OCaml.

I have the solution but I do not understand it.

Define iterup: (int *  → ) → int → int →  → . Iterup takes a function which receives the current number and the accumulator. It increments the counter number from a given start to a given end and applies the function each time. The last argument is the start value of the accumulator.

The solution is

```
let rec iterup f st ed acc = 
  if st > ed then 
    acc 
  else 
    iterup f (st+1) ed (f st acc)
```

What I do not understand is why we take in both n and s as arguments to f in the last part (f n s). What does that get us to when we talk in terms of tail recursion.

Comment: "why we take in both n and s as arguments to f in the last part" because that's how we update the accumulator. "What does that get us to when we talk in terms of tail recursion" it... doesn't have anything to do with that? Suppose that `acc` is an integer starting at zero and `f` is a function that adds the current "index" `st` to it. Call `iterup` with that function, 1, 4, 0 and it should yield back 10 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument provides an *accumulator* which is a very idiomatic way to achieve tail recursion in OCaml. The function provided via the `f` argument provides a way to update that accumulator.

Every path in a recursive function either needs to be an exit from the recursion, or an update to the state passed to the function. Without at least one of each, we get stuck in unbounded recursion: an infinite loop.

Let's look at a call of `iterup`.

```
iterup (fun a b -> a + b) 1 5 0
iterup (fun a b -> a + b) 2 5 (0 + 1)
iterup (fun a b -> a + b) 3 5 (1 + 2)
iterup (fun a b -> a + b) 4 5 (3 + 3)
iterup (fun a b -> a + b) 5 5 (6 + 4)
iterup (fun a b -> a + b) 6 5 (10 + 5)
15
```

At no point do we have to work our way back up the call stack to find the solution, so the stack space used can be optimized to be constant.